# I want to Lock my first two column (tree column)

Tags: extjs4, extjs-mvc

[image]

hi thanks in advance for support my question is i want to lock my first two column from horizontal scroll and rest column scroll using horizontal scroll .

in my first two column one is number column which is simply display number and second is tree view.

i have used its locked property `locked:true`, but its not working so kindly help me to lock my both column.

i have tried following code but its not working and i have attached image for same for better understanding.

```
{
                    xtype: 'treecolumn',
                    header: 'Tasks',
                    dataIndex: 'Name',
                    width: 150,
                    locked:true,
                    field: new Ext.form.TextField(),
                    sortable: false,
                    listeners: {
                        mouseover: function () {
                            loadFn('Task Name', 'basic-statusbar');
                        }
                    },
```

Comment: Try using disabled : true instead of locked : true

Comment: not working in my case but thanks for reply :)

Comment: Is it a Bryntum Scheduler? There might be a little different behavior from standard Ext locking (tree) grids, if yes.